# How can i implement multiple drop-down menu in the action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to add 3 icons on the action bar compat. 2 of them must show a drop-down menu with others options when pressed. How can i do that? Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in your menu's xml by doing:

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/option_group"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_group"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Group">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/option1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_option1"
                android:title="Option 1"/>
           <item
                android:id="@+id/option2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_option2"
                android:title="Option 2"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But i can't try it now. Tomorrow i try it ;)